# Angle math, normalize to [-180,180] and mod vs remainder()

Tags: c, modulo

I need to convert a double/float angle to the range of [-180,180] by adding or subtracting 360. The remainder function works, but I am not sure why.

```
x = remainder (x, 360);
```

Why does this produce a range of [-180,180] and not [0,359.99999...]?

I understand that remainder and mod are the same for positive numbers, but they work differently for negative numbers... I just have not seen a good explanation of what is happening.

I'm happy that this works of course, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: An idiomatic way to convert an angle to the [-pi, +pi] range is `atan2(sin(x), cos(x))`. Just saying..

Comment: FYI, the general way I've converted *any* angle to +/- 180 is:  `(angle%360 + 360)%360 - 180`

Comment: An alternative way (simplifies reasoning, by avoiding negative remainders) is `(angle + 540) % 360 - 180`.  This has only one division, rather than two.

Comment: `angle + 540` loses much precision when `angle` is small.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/remainder):

> The IEEE floating-point remainder of the division operation `x/y` calculated by this function is exactly the value `x - n*y`, where the value `n` is the integral value nearest the exact value `x/y`. When |n-x/y| = ½, the value `n` is chosen to be even.
>
> In contrast to `fmod()`, the returned value is not guaranteed to have the same sign as `x`.
>
> If the returned value is 0, it will have the same sign as x.

What's happening here is the function `remainder(x, y)` rounds to the nearest integer value, times your *y* and then subtracts the result from *x*.

Example:

```
remainder(160.0f, 360.0f)

result = 160 - round(160.0f / 360.0f) * 360
result = 160 - round(0.44f) * 360
result = 160 - (0 * 360)
result = 160.0f
```

Example2:

```
remainder(190.0f, 360.0f)

result = 190 - round(190.0f / 360.0f) * 360
result = 190 - round(0.53f) * 360
result = 190 - (1 * 360)
result = -170.0f
```

Thus you could end up having negative numbers depending on your input variable.

Comment: Avoid using `double` functions with `float` augments.  Suggest `roundf(), `remainderf()`.